# Check for one, two or three digits in a VLOOKUP

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have around 30 numbers which are either 1, 2 or 3 digits which are codes. These codes are attached in front of other numbers. I want to know what code is in front of a number, for example for the number `35467036` the first two digits matches with the code `35`. So I want the output for that to be `1.5`.

This is my current setup, I have a table with all the codes followed by the output in the next column. If all the codes were three digits long I could just do this `=VLOOKUP((LEFT(E6,3)&"*"),D1:E3,2,FALSE)` but they are unfortunately not.

I have also tried using nested IF statements but I can only go so far as 7 levels.

Will this only be possible in VBS or is there anther way?

Edit: [image: Code and Numbers]

The code column is formatted to text. If I enter the value 3 into LEFT it does not work for two digits. Is there anyway I can make it work for 1, 2 and 3 digit codes? Also the codes do not overlap, for example, there isn't going to be 96 and 965 in the code table.

Comment: Are the other numbers leaving code portion aside of fixed length or variable length ie number of numerals.

Comment: @skkakkar the number alone without the code varies in length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seven nested IFs as a limit points to a very old version of Excel. You may want to consider upgrading to a version that is still supported in this millennium.

But your main problem is that the data type of your lookup **value** is text, because you concatenate a string with a wildcard. Whereas your Lookup Table's first column is probably made up of numbers.

In order to solve this you will need to add a Text column to your lookup table that represents the numeric value as a text value.

IF you want to use Vlookup, that helper column will need to be the first column of your lookup range.

You can use an Index/Match instead of Vlookup to be independent of the column order, as this screenshot shows:

[image]

Column H shows the formula that has been applied in column G.

Edit:

According to the screenshot you posted, you want to look up from the table in columns E to F and this table only has the short codes. Therefore, it makes no sense to add a wildcard to the lookup value. You just need to extract the value you want to use for the lookup.

If you want to lookup only two digits, then you need to extract only two digits. Adding a wildcard does nothing to remove the third digit.

In the screenshot below, a helper column feeds the LEFT() function the number of characters to extract, then uses that value in the VLookup.

```
=VLOOKUP(LEFT(A1,B1),$E$1:$F$5,2,FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the response, I have tried using INDEX but it will only with 3 digit codes. Is there anyway I can adapt it for 1 and 2 as well? I have added a screenshot with more information in the question.

Comment: After reviewing your screenshot, I edited my answer with another suggestion.

Comment: I assumed this would be the case, I will have to change my workflow a little bit to get the helper column done but it will have to do. Thank you for your help, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

```
=INDEX($G$2:$G$5,
SMALL(
IF(LEFT(A1,3)*1=$F$2:$F$5,ROW($G$2:$G$5)-1,
IF(LEFT(A1,2)*1=$F$2:$F$5,ROW($G$2:$G$5)-1,
IF(LEFT(A1,1)*1=$F$2:$F$5,ROW($G$2:$G$5)-1))),1))
```

`=INDEX(LookupValues,Small(ArrayOfRowsFromIfStatements,FirstRow))`

This is an array formula so you will need to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> while still in the formula bar.

We use If to build an array of Row numbers where the conditions match or return FALSE if not. The Small function then returns the smallest result in the array which will be the first row where conditions match.

We then index the results returning that row number (-1 deducted from rows to offset the headers).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If your numbers in column A are always 6 digits + the code length you can use this:

```
=VLOOKUP(--LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-6),E2:F5,2,FALSE)
```

[image]